# Identify memory leak in this code while using startTimer and global variable

Tags: javascript, c#, memory-leaks

I have this code in legacy application which gets generated via c#

```
string autoRefreshHandler = string.Format(null, "var autoRefresh = function() {{ {0}; }};", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions));
        string autoRefreshMethod = string.Format(null, "setAutoRefreshTimeout({0}, autoRefresh);", refreshTime);
        string endRequestHandler = string.Format(null, @"function AutoRefreshEndRequestHandler(sender, args)
        {{
            var response = args.get_response();
            if (response && response.get_responseAvailable())
            {{
                // Request completed successfully. Reset Timer.
                {0}
            }}
        }}", autoRefreshMethod);
        endRequestHandler += "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(AutoRefreshEndRequestHandler);";
```

and it outputs as below:

```
var autoRefresh = function() {
    __doPostBack('ctl00$___AutoRefreshControl', '');
};
setAutoRefreshTimeout(60000, autoRefresh);

function AutoRefreshEndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var response = args.get_response();
    if (response && response.get_responseAvailable()) {
        // Request completed successfully. Reset Timer.
        setAutoRefreshTimeout(60000, autoRefresh);
    }
}
```

The complete code would be something like this:

```
var autoRefresh = function() {
    __doPostBack('ctl00$___AutoRefreshControl', '');
};
setAutoRefreshTimeout(60000, autoRefresh);

function AutoRefreshEndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var response = args.get_response();
    if (response && response.get_responseAvailable()) {
        // Request completed successfully. Reset Timer.
        setAutoRefreshTimeout(60000, autoRefresh);
    }
}

function setAutoRefreshTimeout(timeOut, functionPointer) {
    clearAutoRefreshTimeout();

    autoRefreshTimeout = timeOut;
    autoRefreshFunction = functionPointer;

    autoRefreshTimer = startTimer(autoRefreshFunction, autoRefreshTimeout);

    timeOut = null;
    functionPointer = null;
}

function clearAutoRefreshTimeout() {
    clearTimer(autoRefreshTimer);
    autoRefreshTimer = null;
}
```

I notice that this causes some memory leak(open chrome debugging tool or chrome task manger) and I am unable to understand why? Can someone help?

I noticed in chrome Task Manager:

```
+-----------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| MemoryFootprint | JavascriptMemory | LiveCount |             |
+-----------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
|           70028 |            13565 |     10704 | First Load  |
|           70460 |            13564 |  10588    | Second Load |
+-----------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: what is your evidence of a memory leak?

Comment: I have updated the Chrome Task Manager Count. Please see.

Comment: Also, if I leave the application running for 8-10 hours it consumes huge memory and eventually it crashed the browser(after 12 hours of so).Also, if I comment this piece of code then the memory increases after every refresh and it comes back but not when this code is in place.